# Getarray with MySql database returning a wrong array format

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, adodb

I've been using ajax calls with the Adodb library to make dynamic web content, but I don't know why it's not working. Here's my code:

#### HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12 m6">
        <input type="text" onblur="getcedula()" class="validate" id="cedula" name="cedula" value="">
        <label>Cedula </label>
    </div>                       
</div>
```

#### JS

```
function getcedula()
{   
    if($("#cedula").val().length<7){
        alert('La cedula debería contener almenos 7 digitos')
    } else {
        $('#Evaluar').prop("disabled", false);
        find_by_cedula($("#cedula").val());
        alert('La cedula tiene 7 digitos')          
    }   
 }
```

#### JS function:

```
function find_by_cedula(cedula) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: '../procesos/motor_funciones.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
        accion: 'buscar_cedula',
        cedula: cedula
    },
    async: true,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            alert('entro');             
        } else {
            alert('No hubo coincidencias con su busqueda');             
        }
    });
}
```

in my php "motor_funciones.php":

```
case 'buscar_cedula':
    if(isset($_POST['cedula']))
     {
         $cedula = $_POST['cedula'];
     }
     $array  = $objFuncionario->buscar_datos($cedula);
     var_dump($array);              
     //echo json_encode($array);
     break;
```

and in my db conection/query:

```
$query="SELECT  a.nombres nombre, a.apellidos apellido, a.fechanac f_nac, b.numerotel tlf, c.direccion direccion, a.sexo sexo, 
            d.edocivil edo_civil, a.licencia licencia, a.tsangre t_sangre, a.correo correo, a.experiencia experiencia, g.nhijos hijos,
            a.estatura estatura, a.peso peso, a.colorpiel piel, a.colorcabello cabello, a.coloriris iris, a.contextura contextura,
            a.rif rif, a.fechaing f_ingreso, h.rango rango, e.ubicacion ubicacion, f.tipopersonal personal
            FROM tdatospersonales a, ttelefonos b, tdireccion c, tedocivil d, TUbicacion e, ttipopersonal f, thijos g, trango h
            WHERE (a.cedula = '".$cedula."') AND ((a.cedula = b.cedula) AND (a.cedula = c.cedula)) AND ((g.codhijos = a.codhijos) 
            AND (h.codrango = a.codrango) AND (a.codubicacion = e.codubicacion) AND (a.codtipopersonal = f.codtipopersonal) 
            AND (d.codedocivil = a.codedocivil))";
    /*echo $query;
    break;*/
    $result = $this->conn->Execute($query);

    $datos = $result->GetArray();

        return $datos;
```

The select works, because If I use it, it returns me a single row of the database, but when I var_dump the $array, it show me this:

https://scontent-mia1-2.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/16425574_10211366391172911_329247524_n.jpg?oh=8b8ff0323ec257b504f86c5a420b5c83&oe=58922E4E

and it does not allow me to convert it into an json, I still don't get why.